# Learning about Web Crawlers and programming one

Tags: web-crawler

I'm looking for a site to read about web crawlers, to learn about them and to be able to program a simple web crawler. Any suggestions for such a site/sites?

If it's important I can program in C C# and C++ and have no problem to learn a new language for this purpose.

Thenx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Udacity (free online university) has a CS101 course that does EXACTLY what you're asking! Check it out at https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101